# Where should i put the AS Clause for tax rate (VAT_RATE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to put a AS VAT_RATE in this SELECT statement but i don't know where.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY QD.DETAIL_ID) AS No,  
 QD.PRODUCT_ID AS PROD_ID,PM.'+@ProdCode+' AS PROD_CODE,pm.DESCRIPTION AS SHORT_DESC,  
 QD.CORPORATE_PRICE AS Corpo_Price,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),QD.RETAIL_PRICE) AS UNIT_SP,QD.COST_PRICE AS COST_SP,  
 QD.GM,QD.DETAIL_ID,QD.DISC AS Discount,QD.NOTE,

    VAT_RATE=(SELECT VAT_RATE/100 FROM dbo.vat   
    WHERE VAT_ID=(SELECT TOP 1 VAT_ID FROM dbo.product_detail(NOLOCK) WHERE PRODUCT_ID=PM.PROD_ID))

,  
   Img=(SELECT TOP 1 IMAGE_DATA FROM dbo.PRODUCT_IMAGE WHERE PRODUCT_ID=PM.PROD_ID), QD.CostPrice_Percentage  
 FROM dbo.CUSTOMER_QUOTATION_DETAIL(NOLOCK) QD  
 JOIN dbo.product_master(NOLOCK) PM ON PM.PROD_ID=QD.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: You already have a column called `VAT_RATE` so that's not going to work.

Comment: And stop littering your code with [nolock hints](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). You use them only when you understand the consequences, have implemented logic to handle the additional errors it can cause, and have a defined need to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TSQL you there is 3 way to name your columns

1) With the AS (optional in tsql)

```
SELECT QD.PRODUCT_ID AS PROD_ID
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER_QUOTATION_DETAIL(NOLOCK) QD
```

2) Without the AS (since it is optional)

```
SELECT QD.PRODUCT_ID PROD_ID
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER_QUOTATION_DETAIL(NOLOCK) QD
```

3) with an equal sign as if it is a formula

```
SELECT PROD_ID = QD.PRODUCT_ID 
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER_QUOTATION_DETAIL(NOLOCK) QD
```

Specifically for your query this is where the AS should go. 
You would have to remove the equal and put the AS at the end of the sub-query.

Please do note that you have various other issues with the queries that is beyond the scope your original question. If you run into preformance issue, do investigated on the subject of CROSS APPLY / CROSS OUTER JOIN and/or CTE : Common Table Expression.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY QD.DETAIL_ID
        ) AS No
    , QD.PRODUCT_ID AS PROD_ID
    --, PM.'+@ProdCode+' AS PROD_CODE
    , @ProdCode AS PROD_CODE
    , pm.DESCRIPTION AS SHORT_DESC
    , QD.CORPORATE_PRICE AS Corpo_Price
    , CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), QD.RETAIL_PRICE) AS UNIT_SP
    , QD.COST_PRICE AS COST_SP
    , QD.GM
    , QD.DETAIL_ID
    , QD.DISC AS Discount
    , QD.NOTE
    , (
        SELECT TOP 1 (VAT_RATE / 100)
        FROM dbo.vat
        WHERE VAT_ID = (
                SELECT TOP 1 VAT_ID
                FROM dbo.product_detail(NOLOCK)
                WHERE PRODUCT_ID = PM.PROD_ID
                )
        ) AS VAT_RATE
    ,   (
        SELECT TOP 1 IMAGE_DATA
        FROM dbo.PRODUCT_IMAGE
        WHERE PRODUCT_ID = PM.PROD_ID
        ) AS Img
    , QD.CostPrice_Percentage
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER_QUOTATION_DETAIL(NOLOCK) QD
JOIN dbo.product_master(NOLOCK) PM
    ON PM.PROD_ID = QD.PRODUCT_ID
```